# how can i get sum of checkbox value and textbox value in another textbox when checkbox is checked or if checkbox unchecked remove the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<section id="extensions" class=" extensions pad-80">
    <div class="myvolunteer-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h2 class="lg-title text-center"><span>Schemes for Mentally Retarded Children<br /> Mentally Challanged by God</span></h2>
                </div> <!--/.col-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                    <p class="lg-text text-center"></p>
                </div> <!--/.col-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container tr-donate">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Information of Scheme</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning1">
                        <td>1.</td>
                        <td>Rs.25,000.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of adoption of mentally retarded child permanently</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning1" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="25000" />
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning1" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning2">
                        <td>2.</td>
                        <td>Rs.25,000.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of sweet diet one time/ pernanent date in a year</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning2" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="25000" />
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning2" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning3">
                        <td>3.</td>
                        <td>Rs.15,000.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of simple diet one time of time of permanent date in a year</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning3" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="15000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning3" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning4">
                        <td>4.</td>
                        <td>Rs.4,000.00</td>
                        <td>Sheme of one time sweet diet</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning4" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="4000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning4" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning5">
                        <td>5.</td>
                        <td>Rs.2,000.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of one time simple diet</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning5" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="2000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning5" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning6">
                        <td>6.</td>
                        <td>Rs.1,000.00</td>
                        <td>Sheme of one time breakfast</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning6" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="1000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning6" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning7">
                        <td>7.</td>
                        <td>Rs.1,250.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of one time milk</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning7" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="1250"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning7" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning8">
                        <td>8.</td>
                        <td>Rs.50,000.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of school uniform of 100 children</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning8" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="50000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning8" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning9">
                        <td>9.</td>
                        <td>Rs.1,00,000.00</td>
                        <td>Scheme of one month kiranas</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning9" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="100000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning9" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning10">
                        <td>10.</td>
                        <td>Rs.11,000.00</td>
                        <td>The name of donar shall be included in the General list of donors for construction of bhavan of the institution</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning10" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="11000"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning10" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning11">
                        <td>11.</td>
                        <td>Other</td>
                        <td class="btn-parent">
                            <input type="text" id="btn_amount" name="amount" />
                            <span class="bar-amount"></span>
                            <label for="btn-amount" id="lbl_amount">Enter Amount</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="material-switch ">
                                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning11" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="0"/>
                                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning11" class="label-warning"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <label for="amount">Total Amount</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount" id="donationAmount" style="display: block;">
            </div> <!--/.col-->
        </div> <!--/.row-->
    </div> <!--/.container-->
```

how can i calculate the sum of checkbox value and textbox value when checkbox is checked and minus the value of checkbox or textbox when checkbox is unchecked.

i tried jquery for it but it only calculate the value of checkbox but how to calculate the value of textbox

the last textbox named total where the total of checkbox and textbox display please help me

Comment: you'll need more than HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it should do as you want.

```
$("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[type=checkbox], [class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[name=amount]").on("change keyup",function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val())
  }).get();

  sum += parseInt($("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[name=amount]").val().length == 0 ? 0 : $("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[name=amount]").val())

  $("#donationAmount").val(sum)
})
```

**Demo**

```js
function change(obj){
}

$("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[type=checkbox], [class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[name=amount]").on("change keyup",function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val())
  }).get();
  
  sum += parseInt($("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[name=amount]").val().length == 0 ? 0 : $("[class^=someSwitchOptionWarning] input[name=amount]").val())
  
  $("#donationAmount").val(sum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="extensions" class=" extensions pad-80">
  <div class="myvolunteer-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="lg-title text-center"><span>Schemes for Mentally Retarded Children<br /> Mentally Challanged by God</span></h2>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <p class="lg-text text-center"></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container tr-donate">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <table align="center">
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Information of Scheme</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning1">
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Rs.25,000.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of adoption of mentally retarded child permanently</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning1" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="25000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning1" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning2">
            <td>2.</td>
            <td>Rs.25,000.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of sweet diet one time/ pernanent date in a year</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning2" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="25000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning2" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning3">
            <td>3.</td>
            <td>Rs.15,000.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of simple diet one time of time of permanent date in a year</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning3" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="15000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning3" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning4">
            <td>4.</td>
            <td>Rs.4,000.00</td>
            <td>Sheme of one time sweet diet</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning4" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="4000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning4" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning5">
            <td>5.</td>
            <td>Rs.2,000.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of one time simple diet</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning5" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="2000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning5" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning6">
            <td>6.</td>
            <td>Rs.1,000.00</td>
            <td>Sheme of one time breakfast</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning6" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="1000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning6" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning7">
            <td>7.</td>
            <td>Rs.1,250.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of one time milk</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning7" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="1250" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning7" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning8">
            <td>8.</td>
            <td>Rs.50,000.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of school uniform of 100 children</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning8" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="50000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning8" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning9">
            <td>9.</td>
            <td>Rs.1,00,000.00</td>
            <td>Scheme of one month kiranas</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning9" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="100000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning9" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning10">
            <td>10.</td>
            <td>Rs.11,000.00</td>
            <td>The name of donar shall be included in the General list of donors for construction of bhavan of the institution</td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning10" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="11000" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning10" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="someSwitchOptionWarning11">
            <td>11.</td>
            <td>Other</td>
            <td class="btn-parent">
              <input type="text" id="btn_amount" name="amount" />
              <span class="bar-amount"></span>
              <label for="btn-amount" id="lbl_amount">Enter Amount</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="material-switch ">
                <input id="someSwitchOptionWarning11" onclick="change(this.id)" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" value="0" />
                <label for="someSwitchOptionWarning11" class="label-warning"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <label for="amount">Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="donationAmount" style="display: block;">
      </div>
      <!--/.col-->
    </div>
    <!--/.row-->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your desired inputs an exact class name e.g. **price** and then

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".price").change(function(){
       var total=0;

       $(".price").each(function(){
         if($(this).is(":checked")) {total=total+$(this).val()}
        })
   })

   //finally put the total in desired field
   $("input[name=amount]").val(total)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. Also Note that you should only allowed numbers to be enter in textbox and if the textbox is empty it should show 0 as value in it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkboxtotal = 0;
    var textboxValue = 0
    change = function(id){
        if($('#'+id+':checked').length == 1)
          checkboxtotal = checkboxtotal + parseInt($('#'+id).val()) + textboxValue;
         else
          checkboxtotal = checkboxtotal - parseInt($('#'+id).val()) + textboxValue;
        $('#donationAmount').val(checkboxtotal);
    }
    $('#btn_amount').on('input', function() {
      textboxValue = $('#btn_amount').val();
      $('#donationAmount').val(checkboxtotal + parseInt(textboxValue));
    });
});
```